# GPUImage: How to determine average pixel value for given rectangle in processed image

Tags: image-processing, pixel, gpuimage

I am using GPUImage to process incoming video and I would like to then consider a given square subregion of the image and determine the average pixel value of the pixels in that region.  Can anyone advise me on how to accomplish this?  Even information on how to acquire pixel data for a pixel at coordinate(x,y) in the image would be useful.

Apologies if this is a simple question, but I am new to computer vision and the way to do this was not clear to me from the available documentation.  Thank you.

Comment: How large is the subregion? Or is it arbitrary? Does GPUImage let you grab the texture ID and go straight to OpenGL? The answer is likely to be a combination of careful sampling (if you sample exactly between pixels then bilinear filtering effectively averages them) and mip map generation (as lower resolution maps are usually box sampled from the higher resolution versions), and possibly as simple as just drawing that region of the source image to a buffer and sampling the one number directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, use a GPUImageCropFilter to extract the rectangular region of your original image. This uses normalized coordinates (0.0 - 1.0), so you'll have to translate from the pixel location and size to these normalized coordinates.

Next, feed the output from the crop filter into a GPUImageAverageColor operation. This will average the pixel color within that region and use the `colorAverageProcessingFinishedBlock` that you set as a callback. The block will return to you the average red, green, blue, and alpha channel values for the pixels in that region.

For an example of both of these operations in action, see the FilterShowcase example that comes with the framework.

Comment: As a follow up; I'm still curious how you can determine the color of a specific pixel (of coordinates, x, y); is this possible?

Comment: @KeithComito - Your best bet might be to use a GPUImageRawDataOutput and its -colorAtLocation: method. There were some glitches with this, though, and I'm not sure that I fixed all of the bugs with this output type yet.

Comment: The above technique does not work well if there are many rectangular subregions to check.  For instance my current situation is as such for each frame: 1. loop through my hit boxes of interest.  2. crop the frame of said hit box  3.  do average luminosity on the cropped region and in its completion block call hit method on main thread if luminosity is high enough.  This works okay if there are just a few hit boxes, but for the project I am working on there could be dozens at a time which kills the FPS hard.  Do you have any ideas for revisions / workarounds that are less intensive?  Thanks.

Comment: For clarification it is the cropping part of the above that seems to kill the FPS (or is at least the first thing that will kill it).

Comment: Hi Brad, I use GPUImageAverageColor for a still image. It's pretty slow to get the average values from callback block. I guess it depends on frameTime. Is there any way to get the average color instantly? Thanks

Comment: @HaiHw - Shouldn't be the bottleneck here, and has nothing to do with frameTime. That's just a timestamp and doesn't affect processing. Are you sure you aren't doing something else with the photo that is slowing down capture?